# Why I get different results? use name.property and name[property]

Tags: javascript

/*Enumeration

The for in statement can loop over all of the property names in an object. The enumeration will include functions and prototype properties.
*/

//the first code  I write

```
var fruit = {
    apple: 2,
    orange: 5,
    pear:1
},
sentence = 'I have',
quantity;
for (kind in fruit) {
    quantity = fruit[kind];
    sentence += quantity + '' + kind +
                (quantity === 1?'': 's') +
                ', ';
}
sentence = sentence.substr(0,sentence.length-2) + '.';
alert(sentence);
```

//The second code  I write

```
var fruit = {
    apple: 2,
    orange: 5,
    pear:1
},
sentence = 'I have',
quantity;//
for (kind in fruit) {
    quantity = fruit.kind;
    sentence += quantity + '' + kind +
                (quantity === 1?'': 's') +
                ', ';
}
sentence = sentence.substr(0,sentence.length-2) + '.';
alert(sentence);
```

Comment: because fruit.kind is equal to fruit.['kind']. there is no evaluation of kind in your second example.

Comment: Syntax error : `fruit.['kind']` should actually be `fruit['kind']`

Answer (score 1):

The root of this problem is the difference between accessing properties in dot (**obj.prop**) vs array notation (**obj[prop]**).

- **obj.prop** means access the property named **"prop"** that's accessible from the **obj** object.
- **obj[prop]** on the other hand means: determine the string value of the **prop** variable and access the property matching that string value on the **obj** object.

In the first case:

```
for (kind in fruit) {
    quantity = fruit[kind];
}
```

The *kind* variable gets assigned strings "apple", "orange", "pear" during the for loop execution. So you're effectively doing access like this fruit["apple"] (which is equivalent to fruit.apple), fruit["orange"] (or fruit.orange), and fruit["pear"] or (fruit.pear).

In the second case:

```
for (kind in fruit) {
    quantity = fruit.kind;
    ...
}
```

You're always accessing the **kind** property of the **fruit** object. Since the **fruit** object doesn't have the **kind** property, you'll always get **undefined**.

If you want to learn more about how property access is resolved in JavaScript, you can take a look at [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/secrets-of-the-javascript-ninja-second-edition/chapter-7) book - it has helped me.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `kind` is a variable.

When you are writing `fruit.kind`, the JS engine actually interprets it as `fruit['kind']`